# On a system of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system:

$$Y'(x) = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} Y(x); \ \ Y(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $Y$ denotes the column vector of components $y_1, y_2, y_3$ and $Y'$ denotes the column vector consisting of $y_1', y_2', y_3'$.

Let $A$ denote that $3 \times 3$ matrix. The general solution of the system is $Y(x) = e^{Ax}C$, where $C$ is a column vector of constants.

We calculate the eigenvalues of $A$, and find that they are $1$ with multiplicity $1$ and $-2$ with multiplicity $2$.

The Jordan matrix of $A$ is:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

In the cases I have encountered so far, the Jordan of the matrix turns out to be diagonal, or I find that $J$ can be written as $J = \alpha I_n + M$, for some nilpotent matrix $M$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, and in both of such cases the calculation of $e^{Jx}$ is easy. But in this case, I'm unable to find $e^{Jx}$.

Attempt:

I tried to decompose $J$ into the form $\alpha I_3 + M$, namely: $J = -2 I_3 + M$, where:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I noticed that:

$$M^n = \begin{bmatrix} 3^n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \ \forall \ n \ge 2$$

But I couldn't put that to use.

Could someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the matrix $J$ by blocs so with

$$R=\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}$$ we have

$$J=\operatorname{diag}((1),R)$$
Now since $R=-2I_2+N$ then $$\exp(xR)=e^{-2x}(I_2+xN)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2x}&xe^{-2x}\\0&e^{-2x}\end{pmatrix}$$
so

$$\exp(xJ)=\operatorname{diag}((e^x),\exp(xR))$$
and finally the general solution of the system is

$$Y(x)=P\exp(xJ)P^{-1}Y(0)$$

Comment: Thank you. How would it be solved without having to write $J$ by blocks?

Comment: Looking at blocks is the whole point of Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of $Y' = A Y$ when A has eigenvalues -2, -2 and 1 is given by ...

$$ Y = c_1 e^t \vec{v_1} + c_2 e^{-2t} \vec{v_2}+ c_3 t e^{-2t} \vec{v_3}  $$

where $c_1, c_2$ and $c_3$ are constants and

$\vec{v_1}$ is a solution to $(A-I)\vec{v_1}=0$

$\vec{v_2}$ is a solution to $(A+2I)\vec{v_2}=0$

$\vec{v_3}$ is a solution to $(A+2I)\vec{v_3}=\vec{v_2}$